# Variant of the smallest circle problem

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Let suppose you have a finite set of points $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

The [smallest circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) is known as :
\begin{equation}
\underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\min}~\underset{i = 1, \ldots, n}{\max} \| x_i - y \|_2^2
\end{equation}

We know that the center of the smallest enclosing circle is in the convex hull of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (cf this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827210/is-the-center-of-the-smallest-enclosing-circle-in-convex-hull)). We can rewrite this problem as :

\begin{equation}
\underset{\substack{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \alpha \geq 0\\ \alpha^T \mathbf{1} = 1}}{\min}~\underset{i = 1, \ldots, n}{\max} \| x_i - \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j x_j  \|_2^2
\end{equation}

I would like to consider a variation of this problem. Let $k$ be a fixed integer. I would like to know if there was an way of solving this problem if we add as an additional condition that $\forall i = 1, \ldots, n$, $\alpha_i$ must be of the form $\frac{\beta_i}{k}$ where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{N}$ :

\begin{equation}
\underset{\substack{\beta \in \mathbb{N}^n \\ \beta^T \mathbf{1} = k}}{\min}~\underset{i = 1, \ldots, n}{\max} \| x_i - \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j x_j  \|_2^2
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you don't want the $\frac1k$ in front of the first sum with real-valued $\alpha_j$?

Comment: I think you'll encounter three cases here. a) You can generate the exact centre (the one that you get without the integer constraint). b) You can densely fill the space with these linear combinations; then there's no minimum because you can get arbitrarily close. c) You can't densely fill the space with these linear combinations; then you just have to identify the finite number of feasible candidates and find the minimizing one.

Comment: @joriki Indeed, I removed the $\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: The idea is the following. Let us say you have your points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $x_C$ the position of the smallest enclosing circle center. You would like to "teach" to someone where is $x_C$. 

To do this, you will give him a finite number of points taken from $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ (same point can be picked several times) and then he will compute the mean of these points. The constraint is that you have the right to give him exactly $k$ points (mot more, not less).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd overlooked that the $\beta_j$ must sum to $k$. But then the answer is of course yes, there is a way of solving this problem: Just enumerate all admissible $\beta$. You'll need to say something about the complexity of the algorithm you're looking for then.